# Material Design in Android SDK 6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-6.0-marshmallow

This is my **first time** using Android Studio as my IDE in developing Android apps.

I see that my Android Studio's SDK is already version 6.0 (Marshmallow). My question is, **by using SDK 6.0, does it already promote Material Design?** As in through the SDK, it already has Material Design concepts that were introduced back in 5.0 (Lollipop). I'm planning to design my app using Material Design.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes it does, if you want to support earliear versions of Android, you need to add support library.

Comment: Any new feature introduced in particular API level is always forward-compatible, and Google also makes that new feature backward compatible as far back as they can.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Any other issues on using the latest SDK version besides the need of supporting earlier versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of. When you create a new project in Android Studio then you will get the Material Theme by default in which your status bar will have the PrimaryColorDark and Toolbar will have the PrimaryColorLight. You can choose and modify your own themes and colors in styles.xml and colors.xml

Also if you crate a new Activity, you will have 2 options in Android Studio - Blank Activity or Empty Activity. If you choose a Blank Activity then you will get the Material design Floating Button already incorporated in your Activity's layout.

So Android Studio does try to help the developer by introducing little Material Design stuff beforehand. But as you go further you'll have to put things yourself. You might have to import the design library like this in your gradle to use some other widgets -

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

See [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) link to see how to use other Material Design elements in your app.